# Number of orderly sets of linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to calculate number of orderly sets of linearly independent vectors, each set contains $m$ vectors and vectors are from vector space $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$. I really have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m>n$, then the answer is of course $0$. Now suppose $m \leq n$.

For the first vector in the set, there are $q^n-1$ options (since $\Bbb{F}_q^n$ has $q^n$ elements, and it can be anything other than the zero vector). Call this first vector $v_1$. Now, there are $q$ elements in the span of $\{ v_1\}$, and so there are $q^n-q$ options for the second vector. To keep track, we now have $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)$ options. Next, there are $q^n-q^2$ vectors in the span of $\{v_1, v_2\}$ (one for every way to write a linear combination of these vectors). Keep this process going, and we see that the total number of ways to make an ordered pair of $m$ linearly independent vectors is 
$$(q^n-1)(q^n-q)...(q^n-q^{m-1})$$

Comment: Thanks, friend, it helps me a lot.